# Difference between binary to float conversion in C# and C/C++

Tags: c#, c++, c, .net

When converting a binary number in C/C++ and C# we're getting 2 different results by its rounding.
For example - let's take `1000010000010110110000010111111`, in C# - we would get `34.84448` while we would get `34.844479`, why is this minor difference?
Converting in C#:

```
float f = System.BitConverter.ToSingle(bytearray,0);
//bytearray is an array that contains our binary number
```

in C++:

```
int a = 1108041919; //The number that is being represented
float f = *(float *)&a;
```

Comment: They are of the exactly same value, just their string representations are different.

Comment: It's the same number, just rounded to a different number of digits. What exactly is your question?

Comment: @Jose Yes they are, I haven't noticed that, thank you

Comment: It seems highly likely that this is just a difference in textual representation. It would really help if you could provide a [mcve] showing exactly how you're performing the conversion, and what you're using to determine the resulting value.

Comment: And no, this is not a duplicate - these are between double and float, which are using a different standard, which C# and C++ are using the exact same standard (the IEEE 754)

Comment: @JonSkeet I've brought these values from the debuggers. I would edit the post with a small example

Comment: Those debuggers are showing a textual representation. I strongly suspect they're just choosing exactly how to display the same value in two different ways. Do you have any evidence that's not the case?

Comment: Most accurate representation = 3.4844478607177734375E1  http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?hexadecimal=420B60BF

Comment: As said above, you are not comparing like with like. `34.84448` is `34.844479` rounded to 5 decimal places. The only time when the number of decimal places chosen is correct, is when they represent exactly the binary value.

Comment: Your C++ code violates strict aliasing btw (and is therefore Undefined Behavior according to the standard).

Comment: That example isn't complete, and the C# code doesn't compile - `BitConverter.ToSingle` has two parameters, not one. Please help us to help you... but it does look like the exact value is 34.844478607177734375, which is 34.84448 to 5DP, and 34.844479 to 6DP, so both debugger outputs are entirely reasonable for the same value.

Comment: No doubt that this is a textual difference, but in the end of the day how a number is being represented is what is mattered, we're can't understand binary

Comment: @JonSkeet haven't noticed while I was coping it, fixed

Comment: And my C++ code is just a test code that I'm using to see what's going to happen

Comment: "No doubt that this is a textual difference, but in the end of the day how a number is being represented is what is mattered, we're can't understand binary" - so are you actually trying to ask "why do different debuggers show different results for the same value?" That's not what the question asks. That question is more clearly asked by just using a floating point variable directly assigned from a literal - the conversion from 1000010000010110110000010111111 is completely irrelevant here.

Comment: No it's not, it's why 2 different debuggers represent the same float in 2 different representations - see Max's question for more clarification

Comment: Right, you might want to edit the question to make that much clearer then. It *sounds* like you think the result of converting to a `float` value gives different results on the different platforms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many ways to *unambiguously* represent the same floating point value in decimal. For example, you can add arbitrarily many zeros after the exact output (note that since each power of two has a decimal representation of finite length, so does every floating point number).

The criterion for "when can I stop printing extra digits" is usually chosen as "you can stop printing extra digits when you would get the *exact same* value back if you parsed the decimal output into a float again". In short: It is expected that outputting a float "round-trips".

If you parse the decimal representations `34.844479` and `34.84448`, you will find that they both convert back to the floating point value `0x420b60bf` or `01000010000010110110000010111111`. So **both these strings represent the same floating point number.** (Source: Try it yourself on https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html)

Your question boils down to "Why do the different runtime libraries print out different values for the same float?", to which the answer is "it's generally up to the library to figure out when to stop printing digits, they are not required to stop at the bare minimum". As long as you can get the same float back when you parse it again, the library did its job.

If you want to see the exact same *decimal strings*, you can achieve that with appropriate formatting options.

Answer (score 1):

Since the value is the same we could guess that the printing function that is handling the value could be the minor difference in there :-)

Comment: @Martin: It can't be converted to that *exact* value, as that isn't representable in 64-bit IEEE754. The closest *exact* value to 38.84448 is 38.84447999999999723286236985586583614349365234375.

Comment: @Martin `38.84448` is not exactly representable in the floating point format, so clearly it cannot be converted to that.

Comment: @Martin: Because you said that the debugger shows "that the value is converted to 38.84448". That's not the same as "the value shown *in the debugger* is 38.84448". If you really just meant to say that "the value shown in the debugger is 38.84448" then I don't see how it contradicts the answer given at all.

Comment: That is not the case

Comment: @IdoHLevi: Could you give evidence for this *not* being just a textual representation difference?

Comment: @Martin There is no conversion happening here. `1000010000010110110000010111111` and `34.844478607177734375` are both the exact same float, just in different representations. There is no conversion happening if I print it as `0x420b60bf` either.

Comment: @Martin Just that the debugger shows something doesn't mean it's the truth. For all you know, the debugger uses the exact same function for "printing" the value as the user code.

Comment: @Martin: It's entirely reasonable to consider "shown in the debugger" as a "printing function", IMO. The answer here is asserting that the value is the same, and the conversion *to textual form* is the difference here, as opposed to the "binary to float" conversion asserted in the question.

Comment: @Martin The question is not that it is being converted or not, but why am I getting 2 different representations by using the same standard but in 2 different languages

Comment: Yet another case of nit pickers jumping on an innocent comment to try to show off how clever they are.  Well done, you're all so clever pointing out something that was nothing to do with what I said

Comment: @Martin: When two people independently misunderstand you in the same way, you should consider that maybe you weren't clear. It still looks to me like this is a matter of the conversion of floating point number to textual representation that is the problem, which is what this answer says too. Are you still convinced the answer isn't correct? (If you don't mean what I thought you meant in the first comment, then I still don't know what you *did* mean.)